# Plotting a function with reversed axes

Tags: graphing-functions

How could I plot the simple function Q=56-2P, with P on the vertical axis and Q on the horizontal axis?

One problem is that P is a locked variable so would need to use another variable and somehow rename it.

Comment: Try $P = (56 - Q) / 2$

Comment: I don't know what a "locked" variable is. Let $P=0$. Then $Q=56$, right? So, the point $56$ units to the right on the horizontal axis is on the graph, right? Now, let $Q=0$. What does that make $P$? Where does that point go? What do you do with the two points you have now plotted (what kind of geometrical shape is the graph going to be?)?

Comment: Any thoughts on the matter, Orm?

Comment: Thank you @GerryMyerson and caverac . I ended up doing something along the lines of what I think you are suggesting, using caverac's suggested P = (56-Q/)2 and naming the axes accordingly. The shape, of course, is a triangle, representing a standard linear demand curve.

Comment: The plot of the function is a straight line. Together with the axes, part of that straight line forms a triangle. These distinctions are important.